# Can a measure be created in Power BI that references two tables that share no relationship?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to create a matrix table in **Power BI** to display the monthly rent projections for a number of properties. I thought I could simply create a measure that summed the rent from one table and then displayed it by month based on start and end date conditions, but it's been a while since I created any measures and I had forgotten that there needs to be a relationship between columns, among other things.

**Data Model**
[image: Data Model]

A site can have more than one lease associated with it and a lease can have both car-parks and floors associated with it, of which there can be multiple.

In addition to the tables in the linked image, once I had sorted out what I thought would be the easy step I was going to add another table which includes the estimated percentage rent increase and the period in which the increase will occur.

I started out by trying to create a measure along the lines of the following:

```
Matrix Test =
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( Period[Month] ),
    IF (
        Period[Month] >= Leases[Custom Start Date],
        SUM ( Floor_Rent[Annual Rent] ) / 12,
        0
    ),
    0
)
```

This would need to be expanded upon because the end date of a lease would also need to be taken into consideration.

As well as forgetting about the relationship requirements, I've forgotten how to deal with the issue of narrowing down to a single value within a column.

The result is supposed to be something that looks like this:

[image: Example Result]

The blanks indicate a lease that starts in the future or ends within the time-frame displayed.

When I try linking the Leases table and the Period table on **Leases[*Start month for current term*]** and **Period[*Month*]** all I can get to is a table that shows the rent amount in the month the lease starts.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible? If so, how do I accomplish the desired result?

[Link to .pbix file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ui2senpwwfoixz4/Rent%20Forecast%20Example.pbix?dl=0)

**Solution**

The direct answer to the title question is probably 'no', but while trying to figure out how I could use Pratik Bhavsar's LOOKUPVALUE suggestion I had a thought and performed a clumsy google search - *power bi create table for each value in column* - and found [this post](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Create-new-table-with-TOPN-values-for-each-distinct-column-value/td-p/610496). By meddling with some of the DAX in said post I was able to come up with the following:

```
Test Table =
GENERATE(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        VALUES(Leases[Lease ID]),"Lease ID",[Lease ID]
    ),
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        VALUES(Period[Month]),"Month",[Month]
    )
)
```

The result is a table with each Lease ID mapped against each Month. I can't claim to understand exactly how the functions work, and it's not the outcome I thought I needed, but it allows me to achieve exactly what I set out to do.

I've accepted Pratik Bhavsar's answer because it effectively accomplishes the same thing as the work around I implemented. Pratik's solution might be better than what I eventually landed on, but I need to have a closer look at how the two compare.

Comment: Did you try LOOKUPVALUE?

Comment: can you add a sample .pbix?

Comment: @StelioK I've added a link to an anonymised version of the .pbix.

Comment: @LtotheIAM thanks, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @PratikBhavsar Would it be possible to provide an example of how LOOKUPVALUE could be used in this instance?

Comment: Try the approach I mentioned in the answer and let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following DAX will give you a table with all buildings mapped against all rows in the period table, eliminating the requirement of a relationship.

```
SiteToPeriod = 
CROSSJOIN(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(Sites1, "Building name/label", Sites1[Building name/label]),
    Period
)
```

Comment: Between asking you about LOOKUPVALUE and viewing your answer I came up with a solution which is very similar to what you've proposed. I've accepted your answer though because it provides a way to resolve the issue. Thanks :-)

Comment: glad it helped, what did you try

Comment: I used GENERATE, which seems like it's just a more limited version of CROSSJOIN. I've added some notes to the question section above.